# Typescript instantiate exact type of property

Tags: typescript

Let me start by saying that I do NOT want the `typeof` operator.

Suppose I have these classes

```
export function InstantiateMe(): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => {

    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      `instantiate`,
      {
        propertyKey,
      },
      target
    );
  };
}

export class MySuperClass {
  @InstantiateMe();
  property1: MyGoodClass;
  @InstantiateMe();
  property2: MyBetterClass;

  foo: Bar;
}

export class MyGoodClass {
  Name = 'I am good'
}

export class MyBetterClass{
  Name = 'I am better';
}

export class Bar{
  Name = 'I am nothing';
}
```

Now consider the scenario where I want to instantiate all properties which are decorated with @InstantiateMe DYNAMICALLY (i.e. I do not want to do `property1 = new MyGoodClass();`).

Suppose that I somehow got an instance of `MySuperClass` (e.g. `const x = new MySuperClass()`) so both `property1` and `property2` are `undefined`. How would I now, probably using reflection, instantiate these two properties without explicitly knowing what types are accepted.

Note that I do have the `@InstantiateMe` decorator so it would in fact be possible to define /store some extra information there if it were required. If not, please just ignore it.

```
public instantiateAllDecoratedProperties(target: object) : void {
  // Now the fun part.
}
```

The final object should then look like this

```
{
  property1 : {
      Name: 'I am good'
  },
  property2 : {
      Name: 'I am better'
  },
  foo: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The typescript types have no runtime existence. You won't be able to do it.